# Create a new column based on a condition with Spark SQL?

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I want to add a new column which will show a label named "done"

the table looks like this:

```
no    type 
1      a
1      a
1      a
2      a
2      a
2      a 
2      a
```

and the "done" label will be in the new column:

```
no    type    tag
1      a
1      a
1      a      done
2      a
2      a
2      a 
2      a      done
```

So basically, the "done" label will be appeared at the end of each number.

How can I do that with Spark SQL?

Thankyou.

Comment: rows are unordered in SQL tables. How can you know which rows is "at the end"?

Comment: the column "no" is filled by the same number for every 3 and 4 rows. So when 1 is stopped at the 3rd row, then it should be the end. So also, with other numbers, when it's stopped at 4th row, then it's also the end.

Comment: There is no such concept as "the 3rd row". Rows are **unordered** in SQL tables. The 3rd row can be any row.

Answer (score 1):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets (technically multi-sets because they can have duplicates).  There is no ordering without a column that specifies the ordering.  There is no "last" row, because there is no ordering.

Often, such an ordering is available as an id or an insertion timestamp or something else.  If you have such a column, you can enumerate the rows for each `no` and then add the label:

```
select t.*,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by type, no order by <ordering col> desc) = 1
             then 'done'
        end) as flag
from t;
```

Note:  This guarantees that exactly one row with `no`/`type` has "done".  This is true even if the rows are interleaved (based on the ordering column).  If you just want to check if the *next* row is different, then you can use `lead()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

So going without any column for ordering, You can achieve it as follows:

```
select t.*,
       case when row_number() over (partition by no order by no) = 1 then 'done' end as tag
  from your_Table t
order by t.id, tag nulls first
```

Comment: what does t. mean in the query?

Comment: It is the alias given to the table name